# How can I filter the entire admin by event?

Tags: python, django

I'm creating a event bar inventory movement, so I've the following model:

```
class Evento(Model): #Event Model
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _(u"Evento")
        verbose_name_plural = _(u"Eventos")
    autor            = ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    titulo           = CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name=_(u"Nome do Evento"))
    #image           = ImageField(upload_to=upload_to('event/', 'title'), null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_(u"Imagem"), help_text=_(u"Imagem que aparecerá no bloco."))
    #crop            = CharField(choices=CORTE, max_length=200, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_(u"Cortar Imagem"), help_text=_(u"Selecione o ponto de referência para cortarmos a imagem."))
    onde               = CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name=_(u"Cidade"), help_text=_(u"Cidade do evento, exemplo. Uberlândia - MG"), null=True, blank=True)
    telefone           = CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name=_(u"Telefone de Contato"), null=True, blank=True)
    contato         = CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name=_(u"Nome do Contato"), null=True, blank=True)
    inicio           = DateField(help_text=_(u"Preencha com o dia exato do evento"), verbose_name=_(u"Dia do evento"), null=True, blank=True)
    fim             = DateField(null=True, blank=True, help_text=_(u"Preencha com o dia exato de término do evento"), verbose_name=_(u"Dia que acaba"),)
    ativo           = BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name=_(u"Ativo"))
    slug            = SlugField(verbose_name=_(u'Slug / URL'), blank=True, null=True)
    def __unicode__(self): return u'%s'%self.titulo

class Cliente(Model): #Client Model (with card number)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _(u"Cliente")
        verbose_name_plural = _(u"Clientes")
    evento          = ForeignKey(Evento, verbose_name=_(u"Evento"), help_text=_(u"A qual evento esse cliente pertence?"))
    nome            = CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name=_(u"Nome Completo"),)
    cartao          = IntegerField(verbose_name=_(u"Número do Cartão"))
    telefone        = CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name=_(u"Telefone de Contato"), help_text=_(u"Somente numeros, exemplo: 3488888888"))
    rg              = IntegerField(help_text=_(u"Preencha somente os números"), verbose_name=_(u"Número do RG"),)
    ativo           = BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name=_(u"Ativo"))
    slug            = SlugField(verbose_name=_(u'Slug / URL'), blank=True, null=True)
    def __unicode__(self): return u'%s - %s (%s)'% (self.cartao, self.nome, self.evento.titulo)
    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        cartoes = self.__class__.objects.filter(cartao=self.cartao, evento=self.evento)
        if cartoes:
            raise ValidationError('CARTÃO DUPLICADO, FAVOR VERIFICAR A NÚMERAÇÃO INSERIDA.')
        super(Cliente, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)

class Produto(Model): #Product (with code number)
    evento          = ForeignKey(Evento, verbose_name=_(u"Evento"), help_text=_(u"Em qual evento esse produto será utilizado?"))
    nome            = CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name=_(u"Nome do Produto"),)
    codigo          = IntegerField(verbose_name=_(u"Código de Barras"), null=True, blank=True)
    preco_custo     = FloatField(verbose_name=_(u"Preço de Custo"))
    preco_venda     = FloatField(verbose_name=_(u"Preço de Venda"))
    def __unicode__(self): return u'%s'%self.nome

TIPO_MOVIMENTACAO = (

    (1, _(u'Saida de Produto')),
    (2, _(u'Entrada de Produto')),
)

class Movimentacao(Model): #Movement (out/in) 
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _(u"Movimentação")
        verbose_name_plural = _(u"Movimentações")
    tipo                 = SmallIntegerField(choices=TIPO_MOVIMENTACAO, verbose_name=_(u"Tipo"), help_text=_(u"Entrada ou Saída"), default=1)
    evento               = ForeignKey(Evento, verbose_name=_(u"Evento"), help_text=_(u"Para qual evento essa movimentação está sendo feita?"))
    cliente              = ForeignKey(Cliente)
    hora_movimentacao    = DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, default=datetime.now(), help_text=_(u"Data exata da movimentação"), verbose_name=_(u"Data da Movimentação"))
```

So I've a movement model where I'll insert the Type (In/out), the Event (because it will handle with more than 1 event), client card number.

[image]

So what I'm doing is use [django-selectable](http://django-selectable.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to select the client card code, anyway I returns ALL codes and not by evento, thus I realized that I'll need to choose the "event" for each model page, because everything is linked to a "Event" (the client, the movement).

Then, my question is: How can I setup a configuration that will affect all model selections? For example, just after login I'll choose "Iron Maiden Cover" and then, when I go for Movement it will be pre-selected, the same for all models with the "event" field.

Comment: Formatting your code and make sure the indent is correct firstly.

Comment: Pasting error only. But thx